# Jquery Mobile Display Generated Image

Tags: php, jquery-mobile, gd

I am currently using an `iFrame` to display a captcha image. I want to change that for a JQM display where I generate the image in a `pagebeforeshow` event. The current code that is in the php program that generates the captcha image is:

```
$im=genCaptcha();
print base64_encode(imagepng($im));
imagedestroy($im);
```

The `genCaptcha()` function is in an include file. It uses the GD library functions to create the image.

This is my code in the pagebeforeshow event handler:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow','#addList', function(){
     $.post('displaycaptcha.php','',function(data) {
         $("#rList").html('<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + data + '" />');
         });
     });  
 });
```

Any ideas or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bingo: Here's what worked in the PHP script (javascript in question unchanged):

```
ob_start();
imagepng($im);                       
$image = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
print base64_encode($image);
imagedestroy($im);
```